# 'dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:' is deprecated

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

I know that this `question` has already been asked, but how do it fix the problem `referring` to this `line`.

```
 -(void) achievementViewControllerDidFinish:(GKAchievementViewController *)viewController
{
    AppController *app = (AppController*) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    [[app navController] dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

referring to `[[app navController] dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];  'dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:' is deprecated in iOS 6.0`.

Comment: "I know that this question has already been asked".... **and answered**

Answer (score 2):

If you press ALT while clicking on the method in XCode, you can see more information about the method, including the availability. In the Availability section, it will suggest what method to use if the current method is deprecated. For the `dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:`, the suggestion is to use `dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:`. So you can replace it with the latter with completion param as nil.

[image]

Comment: Funny. In the year 2017, Xcode 8 does not show any alternatives or best-practices...

Answer (score 0):

For iOS 5.0+ is

```
- (void)dismissViewControllerAnimated:(BOOL)flag completion:(void (^)(void))completion
```

you can pass Nil in "completion"

Comment: You should use this method with iOS 5.0 and later, not just 6.0 and later.